# How do I make the script send one notification when it shows that an item is in stock?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

As is the code checks if the links in the .txt file are in or out of stock. If the product is in stock a notification will be sent to the recipient(s) every x amount of minutes. How do I make the script send one notification for the item in stock? Then when it scrapes Walmart in the next five minutes how do I skip the url in the list of the product that is available? or in general how do improve the script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import smtplib 
import sys
import requests
import schedule
import time
import datetime
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from termcolor import cprint, colored
from colorama import init
#------------------------------------------------ All Modules required for script are above 
with open('url.txt', 'r') as f: #Opens url.txt file and reads line by line 
    urls = [line.strip() for line in f]

def main():
    for u in urls:
        response = requests.get(u)
        data = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
        out_stock = soup.find("span", class_="display-block-xs font-bold")
        in_stock = not out_stock
        title = colored(soup.find(class_="prod-ProductTitle prod-productTitle-buyBox font-bold").get_text(u), "white", attrs=['bold']) # Finds the title of item  
        product_message = "Item in stock"
        cprint("----------------------------", "blue")

        cprint("Product Name: " + title, "white", attrs=['reverse']) # Gives you the title name 

        if(in_stock): #Checks if item is in stock
            cprint(product_message, "green", attrs=['reverse'])
        elif(out_stock): #Checks if item is out of stock 
            cprint(out_stock.get_text(), "red", attrs=['reverse'])
        else:
            print("ERROR")

def sendemail(): #Email and Text message alert notification
    for u in urls:
        response = requests.get(u)
        data = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')

        #Login here and conncects to the server
        email_sender_account = ""
        email_sender_username = ""
        email_sender_password = ""
        email_smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
        email_smtp_port = 587

        #Sender 
        email_recipients = ["", ""] # Add email or number here in format: "", 
        email_subject = "Phone notification alert"
        email_body = "Product is in stock: " + u

        server = smtplib.SMTP(email_smtp_server,email_smtp_port)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email_sender_username, email_sender_password)

    for recipient in email_recipients:
        message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        message['From'] = email_sender_account
        message['To'] = recipient
        message['Subject'] = email_subject
        message.attach(MIMEText(email_body))
        text = message.as_string()
        server.sendmail(email_sender_account,recipient,text)
    server.quit()

def restart():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %B %d, %H:%M")
    print("\n" * 100)
    print()
    cprint("------------------------------", "blue")
    cprint("Date: " + current_time, "white", attrs=['bold'])

    main()

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(restart)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

To alert the user only once if a item comes in stock, store the in-stock items in a list.

- When an item is in stock, check the in-stock list
- If url not in list, add url to list and send alert
- else skip alert

Here is the updated main():

```
lstInStock = []  # items previously found in stock

def main():
    for u in urls:
        ..........  
        if(in_stock): #Checks if item is in stock
            cprint(product_message, "green", attrs=['reverse'])
            if not u in lstInStock:  # first time in stock
                 lstInStock.append(u)  # skip next time
                 sendemail()  #send alert
             
        elif(out_stock): #Checks if item is out of stock 
            cprint(out_stock.get_text(), "red", attrs=['reverse'])
        else:
            print("ERROR")
```

Note that this will send alerts for every in-stock item on the first run since `lstInStock` is empty.